Selecting a camera based on Field of View (FOV) preference
We are working with a phone which supports both, the Android Camera2 API and ARCore. If at all relevant, the phone is the Samsung S20 FE.
With the Camera2 API we gain access to camera configurations corresponding to different fields of view (FOVs). Specifically, in our case we gain access to frames captured with a narrower FOV (around 60 degrees), or with a wider FOV (around 100 degrees).
With the ARCore API we gain access to camera configurations (ArCameraConfig objects) which correspond to only the narrower FOV (around 60 degrees).
Based on the above, the 100-degree FOV camera seems to be inaccessible by the ARCore API, even though it is clearly supported by the phone hardware.
We have searched thoroughly throughout the ARCore documentation but have not found any reference to this issue.
Questions:

How to extract the wider FOV using the ARCore API?
Is the above perhaps not possible (or at least not guaranteed) by ARCore? If so, why?
Where in the documentation is the above problem discussed?


maybe (wild guess) arcore needs a camera with known intrinsics. maybe that fisheye camera doesn't have them. or maybe it doesn't like fisheye cameras. if you can debug into these libraries, you could look for the code that enumerates the available hardware, or the code that opens or rejects opening a specific device.

@ChristophRackwitz Actually ARCore's role in our app is exactly this: To provide intrinsics. I know it sounds overkill, but we need intrinsics from ARCore because Android's Camera2 API is well-known to not be fully supported by devices out there, especially when it comes to intrinsics. As for ARCore's source code, I don't think this is open. Finally, the wider-angle (100-degree) camera is not really fisheye (i.e. it doesn't suffer from radial distortion). Instead, we find that the 60-degree camera is rather narrow, meaning that the user cannot see as much of the view as we would want.

I believe ARCore runs an extensive calibration process for every device they support, so if they did not calibrate the 100-degree camera, it wouldn't be visible via the API.  If so, there's not much you could do about it - even if you could trick it into showing the camera, it wouldn't have the detailed calibration information ARCore needs.
It seems like the S20 FE has 3 cameras, so the 60-degree camera is likely the wide-angle camera (not the ultrawide or the telephoto), and is probably the default camera view you see in the device's own camera app.  While I agree 60 degrees is a bit narrow for a wide-angle camera, it's not surprising it's the one that's been calibrated for ARCore.
Hopefully ARCore will enable more sensors in the future, but until then, there's probably not much you can do to make it appear.

Thanks for the answer! I think what you say is the most likely scenario: E.g. the 60-degree camera on this phone is indeed the first camera encountered when listing the phone's cameras via the Camera2 API (and its name is "0"), so it's easy to speculate that ARCore indeed treats it as the "default" camera. Before I close the answer, would you know if this is at all explained anywhere in the ARCore documentation?

I didn't have luck finding an explanation of camera selection in the ARCore documentation, sorry. Beyond what the filters in https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/camera-configs allow for.

Thank you, @Eddy Talvala! I understand that we are dealing with an insufficiency of the API due to its internal working, making it impossible to answer the question to the extent I was hoping for (unless an ARCore engineer ever shares more light). Still, your answer helped us a great deal to keep moving ahead! For this reason I accepted the answer.
